# Acceder a datos de una consulta de MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

He estado tratando de acceder a datos de una colección en mongodb y al colocar la consulta en una constante y tratar de mostrar un elemento me da como resultado "undefined", he leído algunas preguntas similares y aplicado lo que responden pero sin éxito, dejo acá a ver si alguno me ayuda.

Consulta en mongoose

```
 let report1 = await Client.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup:
                    {
                        from: "trans",
                        localField: "cli_id",
                        foreignField: "cli_ced",
                        as: "docs"
                    }
                },
            ]);
```

resultado de la consulta en mongoDB

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc9afe9a855fe903cdc458d"),
        "cli_create_date" : ISODate("2020-12-04T03:34:50.382Z"),
        "cli_name" : "James",
        "cli_lname" : "Muller",
        "cli_nac" : "Panameño",
        "cli_id" : "8-741-9875",
        "cli_mig" : "N/A",
        "cli_mig_vig" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "cli_licen" : "AS45887",
        "cli_licen_vig" : ISODate("2022-12-11T00:00:00Z"),
        "cli_email" : "jamesmax@yahoo.com",
        "cli_tel" : "",
        "cli_cel1" : "69110734",
        "cli_cel2" : "",
        "cli_insta" : "",
        "cli_face" : "",
        "cli_dir" : "",
        "cli_sector" : "",
        "cli_street" : "",
        "cli_dir2" : "",
        "cli_home" : "",
        "cli_referido" : "",
        "cli_job" : "Freelance",
        "cli_ocu" : "mensajero",
        "cli_job_time" : "1 año",
        "cli_job_sec" : "Tumba muerto",
        "cli_job_dir" : "calle 2",
        "cli_job_tel" : "",
        "cli_job_boss" : "",
        "cli_job_boss_tel" : "",
        "cli_other" : "",
        "cli_salary" : 1000,
        "cli_fortnight" : 500,
        "cli_cont" : "2",
        "cli_biweekly" : 120,
        "cli_dir_ref" : "",
        "cli_periodo" : "Semanal",
        "ref_name" : "Maria",
        "ref_lname" : "salas",
        "ref_ocu" : "Estilista",
        "ref_cel" : "66987411",
        "ref_name2" : "javier",
        "ref_lname2" : "Perez",
        "ref_ocu2" : "Prograador",
        "ref_cel2" : "65201074",
        "cli_user" : ObjectId("5fb337b20d55e83530ea0992"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "docs" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc9b7a7653ef89748dedb04"),
                        "tran_date" : ISODate("2020-12-04T04:13:52.408Z"),
                        "cli_id" : [ ],
                        "tran_age" : 10,
                        "tran_stat" : 10,
                        "tran_sons" : 3,
                        "tran_house" : 10,
                        "tran_house_time" : 10,
                        "tran_job_time" : 10,
                        "tran_account" : 10,
                        "tran_apps" : 3,
                        "tran_css" : 3,
                        "tran_insurance" : 3,
                        "tran_att" : 3,
                        "tran_talk" : 10,
                        "tran_pan_time" : 10,
                        "tran_legal" : 10,
                        "tran_loan" : 6,
                        "tran_payment" : 6,
                        "tran_fortnight" : 10,
                        "tran_cony_fornight" : 3,
                        "tran_result" : 65,
                        "cli_ced" : "8-741-9875",
                        "__v" : 0
                }
        ]
}
```

Deseo mostrar por ejemplo en un console.log() el elemento tran_age, he intentado colocarlo de muchas maneras, por ejemplo:

```
console.log(report1.tran_age);
console.log(report1[0].tran_age);
console.log(report1.docs[0].tran_age);
console.log(report1.docs.tran_age);
console.log(report1[0][0].tran_age);
console.log(docs[0].tran_age);
```

además he probado funciones como JSON.stringify(), toArray(), con $unwind en el aggregation y nada.
colocando console.log(report1[0].cli_name) si obtengo la respuesta deseada, el problema está en los elementos dentro de docs.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar un proceso de agregación sobre una colección de MongoDB, usando el método [`aggregate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) de un Modelo de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com).

Sin embargo el llamado:

```
let report1 = await Client.aggregate([ ... ])
```

No devuelve los datos requeridos, sino que devuelve un Objeto del tipo [Aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) que no es más que un envoltorio sobre el método `aggregate` del driver de MongoDB para NodeJS.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución al problema es sencilla, debes usar el método [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec), que bien recibe un `callback` opcional, y devuelve efectivamente una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

Tu código podrías escribirlo así:

```
let result1 = await Client.aggregate([ ... ]).exec();
```

Por último, recuerda que cuando se trabaja con Promesas y la sentencia `await`, las mismas deben envolverse en un bloque `try catch`:

```js
try {
    let result1 = await Client.aggregate([ ... ]).exec();
    console.log(result1);
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    // manejo del error
}
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: muchas gracias @Mauricio, lo de los callbacks si me ha sido útil, no lo tenía muy claro. El try catch si lo tenía como me indicas, pero el inconveniente persiste. Usando project en la consulta con el operador **$arrayElemAt**, de esta manera: **tran_age: {$arrayElemAt: [ "$docs.tran_age", 0 ]}** logré tener los valores deseados y no los tipo new array con []. Lo que veo que si trato de usar el operador switch en la consulta me envía $switch found an unknown argument: $docs.tran_age. quería trabajarlo todo desde la consulta pero veo que tendré que buscar otra manera. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción interesante es usar `then` y `catch`:

```js
Client.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: "trans",
      localField: "cli_id",
      foreignField: "cli_ced",
      as: "docs"
    }
  }, ]).exec()
  .then((resultados) => {
    console.log(resultados)
    return
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Problema encontrado", error)
  })
```

Para mas infomación ver:

[**Promesas [Encadenamientos]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas)

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí lo que necesitaba agregando algunos operadores a la consulta, lo coloco por si a alguno le sirva de ayuda si se llega a encontrar con el mismo problema.

```
try {
let report1 =  await Client.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: "trans",
                    localField: "cli_id",
                    foreignField: "cli_ced",
                    as: "docs"
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                   
                    tran_age: { 
                    $switch: {
                    branches : 
                    [
                    { case:{
                            $eq:[{$arrayElemAt: ['$docs.tran_age',0]}, 3]}, then: "18-21" },
                    { case:{
                            $eq:[{$arrayElemAt: ['$docs.tran_age',0]}, 6]}, then: "22-25" },
                    { case:{
                            $eq:[{$arrayElemAt: ['$docs.tran_age',0]}, 10]}, then: "25 en adelante" }], 
                    default : 0 }},
                }
            }
        ]).exec();
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
```